# Disposable object is null after subscription

Tags: android, java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java2

In the below code, I created an example to learn functional programming using Rx. I am trying to handle a `HandlerThread` as observable. In `onResume()`, I subscribe for `Single.just` observable to start the
`HandlerThread`.

For `SingleObserver` callbacks, despite receiving the values in `onSuccess()`, the `Disposable` object in `onSubscribe()` is always `null`.

I also posted the logcat. Please have a look at it, and please let me know how why the `Disposable` object `d` is `null`.

**code**:

```
onResume() {
    this.mMyHandlerThreadInitSingleObs = Single.just(this.getInitializedHandlerThread())
            .map(myHandlerThread->{
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "BEFORE .start()");
                myHandlerThread.start();
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "AFTER .start()");

                return this.mMyHandlerThread;
            });
    this.mMyHandlerThreadInitSingleObs
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this.getSingleObserver());
}

private SingleObserver<HandlerThread> getSingleObserver() {
    String TAG_LOG = ActMain.TAG_LOG + "." + "getSingleObserver()";
    return new SingleObserver<HandlerThread>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, "[onSubscribe] d: " + d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(HandlerThread is) {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, "[onSuccess] is: " + is);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, "[onError]");
        }
    };
}
```

**logcat**:

```
2018-12-22 14:56:50.329 12611-12611 V/ActMain: onStart
2018-12-22 14:56:50.332 12611-12611 V/ActMain.MyHandlerThread: constructor called
2018-12-22 14:56:50.333 12611-12611 V/ActMain.getSingleObserver(): [onSubscribe] d: null//<--------------------
2018-12-22 14:56:50.349 12611-12611 D/ActMain.onResume(): BEFORE .start()
2018-12-22 14:56:50.349 12611-12611 D/ActMain.onResume(): AFTER .start()
2018-12-22 14:56:50.350 12611-12630 V/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: ..
2018-12-22 14:56:50.350 12611-12630 D/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: this.getLooper(): Looper (my HandlerThread, tid 416) {2f35ee2}
2018-12-22 14:56:50.363 12611-12630 I/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: [onSubscribe] d: null
2018-12-22 14:56:50.377 12611-12633 D/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared.emitter.onComplete():: this.getLooper() initialized: Looper (my HandlerThread, tid 416) {2f35ee2}
2018-12-22 14:56:50.377 12611-12633 I/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: [onComplete]
2018-12-22 14:56:50.425 12611-12611 V/ActMain.getSingleObserver(): [onSuccess] is: Thread[my HandlerThread,5,main]
2018-12-22 14:56:50.514 1700-1724 I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.amrbakri.rxhandlerthread_01/.ActMain: +340ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is an interesting question.  From the docs for RxJava2 ([Single](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html))

> Single behaves similarly to Observable except that **it can only emit
>   either a single successful value or an error** (there is no "onComplete"
>   notification as there is for an Observable).
>
> The Single class implements the SingleSource base interface and the
>   default consumer type it interacts with is the SingleObserver via the
>   subscribe(SingleObserver) method.

It looks like your using the `SingleObserver` rather than the `DisposableSingleObserver`.

The docs mention that:

> Note that by design, **subscriptions via subscribe(SingleObserver) can't
>   be disposed from the outside (hence the void return of the
>   subscribe(SingleObserver) method)** and it is the responsibility of the
>   implementor of the SingleObserver to allow this to happen. RxJava
>   supports such usage with the standard DisposableSingleObserver
>   instance. For convenience, the subscribeWith(SingleObserver) method is
>   provided as well to allow working with a SingleObserver (or subclass)
>   instance to be applied with in a fluent manner (such as in the example
>   above).

So try doing this instead:

```
Disposable d = Single.just("Hello World")
    .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            System.out.println("Started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String value) {
            System.out.println("Success: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Stackoverflow deleted my post because of this one. But this is different and my code is not like this. I use RxJava and d in onSubscribe method is null, why?

Comment: If your situation is different, I'm not sure why SO would delete it.  It's really hard to identify your issue without your code.  Maybe try again and word it a bit differently? I'm not sure, sorry man. @HHooshyar